# Need help in compiling lighttpd on MacOSx

Tags: macos, lighttpd

I try download lighttpd 1.4.23 source, and compile it on MacOSX 10.5.5.
This is the error I am getting:

$ ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: running `libtoolize --copy --force'
./autogen.sh: line 19: libtoolize: command not found

I tried ask the same question on lighttpd forum, but I can't get any help there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

libtoolize is part of GNU libtool, a package for building libraries portably. On the Mac, one option for getting it is to use MacPorts, a package manager which works in a similar fashion as Gentoo and FreeBSD, in that it compiles packages on your machine. See http://www.macports.org/install.php.

Beware, though, that it will be installed as glibtoolize, i.e. with a 'g' prefixed. That is a standard way to make GNU tools live in parallel with UNIX tools of the same name, that might be present (even though there isn't one in this particular case).

The command for installing libtool from MacPorts is: `sudo port install libtool`

Add a '-d' flag after the 'port' command to see the build output.

Comment: why not `sudo port install lighttpd`

Comment: If all you want is to have lighttpd, then that is better. If one wants to hack on lighty itself, and that way I interpreted the question, then my answer applies. Only then :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to install lighttpd 1.4.25 on Mac OS X 10.6.2. If I remember correctly, the same thing worked for me in a recent version of Mac OS X 10.5.

#### Install Xcode Developer Tools

Either install them from the DVD that came with your Mac (under Optional Installs) or download them from Apple's [developer page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/).

#### Install PCRE

```
curl -O http://softlayer.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/7.9/pcre-7.9.tar.gz
tar xzf pcre-7.9.tar.gz
cd pcre-7.9
./configure
make && sudo make install
cd ../
```

#### Install lighttpd

```
curl -O http://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/lighttpd-1.4.25.tar.gz
tar xzf lighttpd-*.tar.gz
cd lighttpd-*
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

Note that the URLs above will quickly go out of date; you may need to download the latest versions of the .tar.gz packages from a different location.